# Disable soft keyboard in SearchView Android

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

I have created a custom keyboard which I want to use whenever my SearchView is active. Right now, the custom keyboard appears underneath the default soft keyboard. I can't seem to get it to hide properly.

I have used the `InputMethodManager` to try to hide it with `hideSoftInputFromWindow`. At first click on the SearchView this does not seem to have any effect. But if I try to touch the SearchView a few more times, the touch is recognized as an onTouch event, and the default keyboard is hidden (I have defined the `InputMethodManager` in an onTouchlistener).

I have tried to put `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in the Manifest under the activity tag. Did nothing.

I have set the input type of the SearchView to null, no success.

It seems the SearchView overrides my code when it is first focused. Does anyone have a workaround for this?